# ROI with SURF invalid argument

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, roi, matlab-cvst

I have the following line of code:

```
x=ginput(1);
y=ginput(1);
limits = [x(1) x(2) abs(x(1)-y(1)) abs(x(2)-y(2))]
boxPoints = detectSURFFeatures(boxImage, 'MetricThreshold',100,'ROI',limits);
```

And this gives the following error:

```
Error using detectSURFFeatures>parseInputs (line 100)
Argument 'ROI' did not match any valid parameter of the parser.
```

I'm on matlab R2013a

According to http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/detectsurffeatures.html#namevaluepairarguments

This should be totally valid as far as I can tell. Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is apparently a new feature in R2014a. Who knew.